# Multiple emails configurations to send emails (if admin have multiple emails then admin need to choose )in Django using python

Tags: django, python-3.x

> sending an email from one email is working fine, but if we want send
>   an email to user from multiple emails(i have 3 emails from that i need
>   to choose any one and receiver get email whichever i chose ) so please
>   help me I'm new to Django and Python

Answer (score 1):

This is how to send multiple email in django.

```py
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com', 'anotherTo@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

Here's the django documentation. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/

I hope this help. Also beginner in django :)

Comment: Thank Q. but i need configure multiple emails in settings.py to send emails from those multiple emails depends one the user (admin/sender)

Comment: Here's my sample setting. Can send multiple email.
`EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = socket.gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com')
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'test@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True`

Comment: that is only for single email configurations but i need multiple emails configurations requirement case is when the admin wants to give replay to user then the send emails another one we need so

Comment: finally i got the answer using some lengthy process